# "Addable" similar n-gons

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be three similar n-gons with the following property:

- One can glue together $X$ and $Y$ along one of the edges to get $Z$.

Examples would be rectangular triangles and also rectangles where the ratio of the sides is $\sqrt{2}$.

Already with quadrilaterals it becomes hard to fulfil the condition and it is probably worse with higher n-gons.

Are my examples the only existing ones? Can someone give and prove a list of all such n-gons?

Comment: FYI: When two *identical* polygons join (perhaps along more than one edge) to form a similar copy, you have an order-$2$ (or rep-$2$) ["rep-tile"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rep-tile).